# Determine $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ the unit intervall with the Lebesgue-measure and
> >     $$
> > \mathcal{F}:=\left\{A\subset [0,1]: A\text{ or }A^C\text{ countable}\right\}.
> > $$
> >     Determine $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})$ for $X\in L_{\lambda}^1$.

Is it possible that $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})$ can be any function, that is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?... That's my result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for each $A\in\mathcal F$, $\lambda(A)\in\{0,1\}$ hence a random variable measurable for $\mathcal F$ is almost surely constant.

Comment: I think it is $E(X|\mathcal{F})=E(X)$, but I cannot justify it. I want to use these theorem: $g=E(X|\mathcal{F})\Leftrightarrow~\forall A\in\mathcal{F}: \int_A g\, d\lambda=\int_A X\, d\lambda$. So my suggestion is $g=E(X)$. Does this fit to this theorem, I do not see it. If $\lambda(A)=0$ then both integrals are $0$, ok. But what's if $\lambda(A)=1$?

Comment: The integral over a set of full measure is the integral over the whole set. This because the integral over a null set is $0$.

Comment: Could you explain more detailed why the integral over a set of measure one is the integral over the whole set? Anyway then it is for $A$ with $\lambda(A)=1: \int_A E(X)\, d\lambda=E(X)\int_{\Omega}\, d\lambda=E(X)=\int X\, d\lambda=\int_A X\, d\lambda$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that the integral over a set of measure $0$ is $0$? Then consider complements.

Comment: I've proved that first for elementar functions, then for non-negative measurable functions and then for any (measurable) function.

Comment: Is it ALWAYS that the integral over a set with measure 1 is 1?

Comment: For and integrable function, yes.

Comment: Then f.e. it is alway $E(X)=\int X\, dP=1$?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused now. Hope that question is not too silly.