# Conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$ where $\mathcal{G}$ is $\sigma$-algebra of countable and co-countable sets.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

We have $\left((0,1), \mathcal{B}(0,1), \lambda|_{(0,1)} \right)$ and r.v. $X(\omega) = \cos (\pi \omega)$ and $\mathcal{G} = \{A \subset (0,1): \text{A is countable or $A^C$ is countable}\}$. What is the $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G})$?

We have $\lambda(A) \in (0, 1)$ due to the properties of $\lambda$-measure. Can I just assume that $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(X) $ and then just calculate that as$ \int_\Omega X d \lambda = \int_0^1cos(\pi x)dx = 0$? If yes, why?

This is related to the [this SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683548/determine-mathbbex-mathcalf) but I could not get the grasp of the answer there.

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ has the property that every set in it has measure zero or one; such a $\sigma$-algebra is said to be *almost trivial*.  It is a good exercise to show that whenever $\mathcal{G}$ is almost trivial then $E[X \mid \mathcal{G}] = E[X]$ for any $X$.  (But you do have to prove it; you can never "just assume" something if you don't know that it can be proved.)  Intuitively, $\mathcal{G}$ contains "no information".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X |\mathcal G)=0$ because $0$ is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal G$ and $EXI_B=0$  if either $B$ or $B^{c}$ is countable. The first case is trivial since Lebesgue measure of any countable set is $0$. For the second case use the fact that $\int_B \cos (\pi \omega)d\omega =\int_0^{1} \cos (\pi \omega)d\omega-\int_{B^{c}} \cos (\pi \omega)d\omega=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in the line of the link in your question.

Suppose that $Y$ is a random variable that is measurable wrt $\mathcal G$ and that $F$ is its CDF. Then for every $y\in\mathbb R$ we have $\{Y\leq y\}$ is countable or its complement is countable. That means that $F$ can only take values in $\{0,1\}$ which on its turn leads to the conclusion that $P(Y=c)=1$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$.

We conclude that $\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ and then find:$$c=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid\mathcal G]]=\mathbb EX=0$$For the last equality see the answer of Kavi.